# is there any way to check DevPack .netframework 4.7.2 is installed?

Tags: windows, powershell, .net-framework-version

I have installed .NetFramework 4.7.2 and then installing DevPack for it. where can i find if DevPack installed on servers? Maybe in register or somewhere else. I'd happy if you can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution could be to query the registry to determine whether the DevPack has been installed.

> HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall  HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Example:

```
PS C:\> Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*", "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" | Where {$_.DisplayName -like '*.NET*' -and $_.DisplayVersion -like '4.7*'} | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion

DisplayName                                       DisplayVersion
-----------                                       --------------
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7 Developer Pack       4.7.2053      
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7 SDK                  4.7.02053     
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7 Targeting Pack (ENU) 4.7.02053     
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7 Targeting Pack       4.7.02053
```

Hope this helps.